# Classes: Interacting with 2 class instances in one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

It's my first time with classes in python and I quickly wrote a simple class which lets you move rocket by coordinates. I don't know though how to make a function called let's say "distance" that would return distance between two different instances(rockets). Just to be clear, I know how to calculate the distance, I don't know how to build a function

```
class Rocket:

    def __init__(self , start = (0, 0)):
        self.start = start
        self.x = self.start[0]
        self.y = self.start[1]
        if not self.crash():
            self.start = (0,0)
            print("You crashed!! Your position has been restarted to (0,0)")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "tbd"

    def get_position(self):
        return "Your curret posiiton is {}".format(self.start)


    def move_side(self,x):
        self.x += x
        self.start = (self.x, self.y)

    def move_up(self,y):
        self.y += y
        self.start = (self.x, self.y)
        if not self.crash():
            self.start = (0,0)
            print("You crashed!! Your position has been restarted to (0,0)")

    def move(self,x,y):
        self.x += x
        self.y += y
        self.start = (self.x,self.y)

    def land_rocket(self):
        self.y = 0
        self.start = (self.x,self.y)

    def crash(self):
        if self.y >= 0:
            return True
        return False

    def distance(self,other):
        return "???"
```

Comment: You don't have a code you have tried here, which should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class method that takes an extra argument, which is the object from which you want to calculate the distance.

To apply the cartesian distance formula, know that `**` stands for exponentiation and that you can import `math.sqrt` for square root.

```
import math

class Rocket:

    ...

    def distance(self, other):
        return math.sqrt((self.x - other.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other.y) ** 2)
```

The above code only requires `other` to have `x` and `y` attributes, it does not need to be a `Rocket` instance.